# How do I use a webhook using an existing bot with discord.py

Tags: discord.py, webhooks

I am trying to make a webhook where when a specific yt user posts a video I want my bot to post an emded link and text, however the catch is I am trying to add this to an existing discord.py bot that does other functions. I am using 'If this then that' to create the webhook but I don't know URL to use on this [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsHCd.jpg) in the Then That section. Am I doing it wrong? Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. You can paste your image here with you question instead of giving links.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
import requests

discord_webhook_url = 'webhook url'
Message = {
    "content": "some stuff here"
}
requests.post(discord_webhook_url, data=Message)
```